# How do I pass the correct format for the Date in ts?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I want to pass the value in a local storage service but am unable to parse because of no date format support. How should I proceed?

```
 description,
      TaskDate: ,
      TaskTime: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize/deserialize a date for use with `localStorage` like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhAIGUFMCcEsCGAbeAvawAi0DOclUNxFwtEAXacAMwHtZwBXfcAd3goAtxk6BjFJAqw6iAObUQwALAAoGkwB2-CvDpLwAE0rQYsLdQAU8XHQBc4XCPhLxASkvkqAbnmKVajdt37D4Ix0qJ11HKxs7NwVlVXVNIL04fxMlAAcmCktrBDtwAB8yUPAAb3lwcFhoCiZYTQoAT1ToOhpwW3SKcABeHvAAcmzbcT7wAH5wJWg2QqoUjvtwS3aMgDoKOgBJSAB5YRzxI3sogF95M7lgYHAAVXxzc-4Na3CGCWgAaWh67v6AW3qALQJPpRR5KZ4JH6TabOaCHKLyMHPfAIFDoaBaH4JPxwhJHeR8QTIYSvSQrfAUDZUX5Gaykj5fAA0VgIaIwWnxckRT06nGgvx+hKE61gbxWkkp1NpIren3qnPk8FaJmpC1KcnKSM6hhRhHRmK6PioOJV-M5mqedGQ0BWfAOxWgAEcmChLAlxVUACrwX5whY9Q061lEDEeije32HY5HcCXcAiJjQeSnORAA)

```ts
/** Serialize/Deserialize a Date for use with localStroage */
function dateSerde (iso: string): Date;
function dateSerde (date: Date): string;
function dateSerde (input: string | Date) {
  return typeof input === 'string' ? new Date(input) : input.toISOString();
}


// Use:

const storageKey = 'my-date';
const date = new Date();

const serialized = dateSerde(date);
localStorage.setItem(storageKey, serialized);

const item = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);

if (item) {
  const deserialized = dateSerde(item);
  console.log({equal: date.getTime() === deserialized.getTime()}); // true
}
```